# Date today from a Display Item insert to database

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I made a table that has a column `Date_Created` in it. And in my form I put a display item above having a formula of `sysdate` so that each time the form runs and insert new data, the date will always e updated but when I looked up into the database, `Date_Created` is blank!
What causes this problem? tnx

screen shots:

http://static.tumblr.com/ezdv8nl/YcUmu2vcc/untitled_1.jpg

My code for the submit button:

```
    DECLARE
    adminPass VarChar(20);
    alert Number;

BEGIN

        IF :USERS.PASS != :USERS.PASS2 OR :USERS.PASS IS NULL THEN
            MESSAGE('Passwords did not match');
            GO_ITEM('PASS2');

        ELSIF :USERS.ACCESS_LEVEL = 'admin' THEN
            SELECT password
            INTO adminPass
            FROM admin_pass_history
            WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM admin_pass_history);

            IF :USERS.ADMIN_PASS IS NULL THEN
                MESSAGE('Please enter the Administrator Password');

            ELSIF :USERS.ADMIN_PASS != adminPass THEN
                MESSAGE('Administrator Password did not match');
                GO_ITEM('ADMIN_PASS');

            ELSE
                COMMIT;
                alert:= show_alert('USER_CREATED');

                IF alert = alert_button1 THEN
                    OPEN_FORM('C:\Documents and Settings\Richzer Cruz\Desktop\LOGIN.fmx');
                END IF;

            END IF;
        END IF;

        EXCEPTION
            WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                MESSAGE('Administrator Password did not match');
                GO_ITEM('ADMIN_PASS');

    END;
```

Comment: i don't think codes are necessary. Besides I dont have `insert` sql in my codes cause forms builder adds the data without it. but i can post some screen shots.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to make sure that your display item is a database item property set to Yes.

Comment: yes it is. and the column name is set also to DATE_CREATED which is the column name in the db

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Hard to say without seeing the form in form builder. I assume that you have the item in the same database block as the items for the other columns? I personally have never used a display item for updating of the database so I'm not sure if that can be the problem. What if you change the item from display item to a regular text item? If that is working then you can disable the item so that none can change the item manually.

Comment: I did that already. changing it to text item has no effects either.

Comment: Sorry. but with the given information I can't help you any more. Realy should need to ahve a look at your fmb file.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember items with formulas are not saved to database. Remove formula and use WHEN-CREATE_RECORD trigger.